# Can I share the VCC (5V) on my Arduino Pro mini with multiple modules?

Tags: sensors, power, bluetooth, arduino-pro-mini, current

Right now I am onto a new project where I am building an obstacle avoiding landrobot.

I use an arduino pro mini as my board and I have a few hc-sr04 sensors here at home. The problem I have right now is that many pins is occupied with other modules, motors and bluetooth.

So right now on my Pro Mini the VCC is occupied by my BLE device and I was wondering if there is a possibility to solder a few wires together so that my BLE device share the same VCC with 4 other hc-sr04 modules? I do this regularly with the GND where I solder multiple wires together and share the GND across different modules which works fine.

I have soldered a wire looking like this:
[image]

The idea is to power the arduino itself through the "RAW" pin. I have a power distribution board that connects to my battery/motor and the VIN pin of the PDB goes to the "RAW".

I try to avoid a breadboard to decrease the size as much as possible so if it were to be possible then that would be the optimal solution for this project.

Something I am also wondering is if it is possible to use these hc-sr04 on both the analog pins and also the digital pins. I do not have enough space to fit all the sensor cables on the digital pins but if I use the analog pins also then they all would fit. Is this possible? Each HC-sr04 has two cables that needs to be inserted (Trig and echo) and right now I have 3, 4 free and all the analog pins 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 which is enough to fit them all.

[image]

Comment: You can indeed use analog pins as digital pins.

Comment: if your Vin=Vcc, then you can go up the supply's limit, if not, then limit it to the capabilities of your voltage regulator.

Comment: I use the "VCC" pin on the arduino pro mini to power the BLE and that is the pin i was thinking about sharing. I do not have a VIN on my arduino pro mini i think

Comment: This is how I will setup the entire project: I use a power distribution board that connects to my 4s lipo battery/motor. The GND of the power distribution goes to the GND and the VIN goes to the "RAW" of the arduino pro mini.

Comment: RAW is connected to the input to the regulator, whereas VCC is connected to its output. As a thumb of rule, you should connect your power source (battery, AC/DC adapter, whatever...) to RAW and then supply power through VCC to all the remaining modules (as long as maximum current output and power dissipation in the regulator are respected).

Comment: You mention motors. These typically consume a lot of power in comparison to the electronics in a project and it's not unusual to power them separately, as in [this answer]( http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/36558/31794). That's where I would start, and then look at using on-board regulators on other boards, where available, as discussed in the answers to [this question](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/36544/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that as long as the total current draw of the modules you attach to VCC doesn't exceed the on-board regulator maximum current output.

The Arduino Pro Mini has a MIC5205 regulator capable of [delivering up to 150 mA](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino-Pro-Mini-schematic.pdf), which is quite low if you plan to attach many modules to its output. So you should look through your modules datasheets and find out the total current draw, including the Pro Mini board itself, and check that against the 150 mA limit.

According to the [HC-SR04 datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Proximity/HCSR04.pdf), each module draws 15 mA. The Arduino Pro Mini itself draws about [about 20 mA](http://www.home-automation-community.com/arduino-low-power-how-to-run-atmega328p-for-a-year-on-coin-cell-battery/). The [BLE module peak current consumption](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-low-energy/nRF8001) is 12.5 mA at active RX and 11 mA at active TX, so lets say 25 mA peak current draw for the BLE module.

Everything adds up to a worst case 105 mA peak current draw, within the maximum 150 mA limit. So **it should be fine**, but I would avoid connecting much more modules to that VCC rail.

[image: MIC5205 on board the Arduino Pro Mini]

**ADDED according to your additional question:**

If you run out of digital I/O pins, you can use the analog pins as digital pins if needed.

Additional note (thanks go to @jwpat7 for pointing this out in the comments):

However, this is true only of A0–A5 on most Uno and Nano Micro Arduinos, and not true of A6, A7 (except on -PB MCU models like ATmega168PB and ATmega328PB, where A6, A7 can be used as digital pins).

Comment: Alright! I added a bit more info also if you missed it (in case it changes anything in your resonse).I use a power distribution board that connects to my lipo battery/motor. The GND of the power distribution goes to the GND and the VIN goes to the "RAW" of the arduino pro mini. So my lipo 4s will power the arduino pro mini itself

Comment: If i try it out, can it harm/damage the arduino pro mini/the other modules?

Comment: Avoid using the data pins as supply rails for your modules, at any cost. It may work but it's a bad idea.

Comment: what is a data pin? is that the "raw"?

Comment: @EnricBlanco: why is it a bad idea if it works?

Comment: @dandavis Because 1) it will increase power dissipation in the ATmega, 2) the supply current will be limited to 20 mA per pin, and 3) the output voltage of the pin isn't regulated and will drop with increasing load.

Comment: So just to confirm. This is the schematic (but I use a pro mini instead of uno) https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpb43.png so on Uno it is named "VIN" but on Arduino Pro Mini it is named "RAW" and that is where I insert it. Then I hook the BLE and all the hc-sr04 VCC/VIN to the VCC of the arduino pro mini that should land at 105mA peak as you mentioned above. Should work fine right?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your diagram. What are the 4 ESC modules? How do the motors relate (connection-wise) to the arduino and its modules (including those ESCs), and how are the motors powered? Are you aware that switching high currents on/off (something that happens often when motors are involved) can induce high voltage spikes in shared power supply rails that can easiky fry regulators unless properly decoupled? Please understand that is unrealistic for you to expect that we can debug your entire project in the comments of a limited scope answer of a Q&A site.

Comment: I'm happy to keep helping, but it would be better to ask new focused and scope-limited questions as you come across new challenges and or doubts, instead of updating this post. That would be a better fit to the Q&A nature of this site, and will probably get you better overall answers and help.

Comment: Ok! I insert the lipo battery to the power distribution board and that powers both motors and the arduino. I succesfully make it work with a arduino uno so it should work with a arduino pro mini also i assume! :) Anyway aprpeciate your help a ton

Comment: If the Uno tolerated it then the Pro Mini should be fine as well.

Comment: I see [a lot of demos](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/blink) powering LEDs (~2-15ma) from GPIO, and a lot of modules (ADCs, DHTs, etc) use less than 1ma; "at all cost" is too broad imho; follow the datasheets and you're fine.

Comment: @dandavis Fair enough. I agree that powering a LED from a GPIO should be fine because it's fairly tolerant to voltage as long as more than the forward voltage can be supplied and current is limited by a resistor. But I'll be very hesitant of connecting the power rail of any IC to a GPIO pin for a lot of reasons from noise to load effects. Of course, YMMV.

Comment: “If you run out of digital I/O pins, you can use the analog pins as digital pins if needed”,  is true only of A0–A5 on most Uno and Nano Micro Arduinos, and not true of A6, A7 [except on -PB MCU models like ATmega168PB and ATmega328PB, where A6, A7 can be used as digital pins]

Comment: @jwpat7 Thank you, I'll correct  that.

Comment: I connected everything now and powered up the arduino through USB and it seems to work well! :) The BLE is starting up and i seem to get results from all the hc-sr04 sensors. I will test it further tonight. Now it will be interesting to see if I can power up the arduino itself through the RAW via a lipo/power distribution setup!

Answer (score 2):

To be frank you can use even your analog pins as digital pins as the analog pins are also digital pins but they are more enhanced

If you use a common Vcc you may not have enough power left for your board and when you share your ground it doesn't matter a lot as it is the -ve lead of your power  source and you may use an external power source

Comment: Ok. So sharing VCC can be problematic then but can work? If it doesnt work I assume breadboard is the only option left

Comment: I think it will not work

Comment: Of course! This one: https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-the-nrf8001-bluefruit-le-breakout/hooking-everything-up

Comment: I think it will not work as you have tied too many things to a Mini board You may use an external battery or power source

Comment: This is how I will setup the entire project: I use a power distribution board that connects to my lipo battery/motor. The GND of the power distribution goes to the GND and the VIN goes to the "RAW" of the arduino pro mini. On the "VCC" i have the BLE currently and that is where I also plan to put the hc-sr04 sensors

Comment: So the idea is that the lipo battery will power the arduino through the "RAW" pin

Comment: Yes you can but I prefer to use a lm805 ic

Comment: Sagnik Peadhan, regarding “you can use even your analog pins as digital pins as the analog pins are also digital pins”, see my comment to Enric Blanco's answer